# Append Div Class with Ajax Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an Ajax script that reads an XML file and appends each node inside a div with an ID "links." The script is working OK, but I'd like to display each result within a class "col-md-3".

Here's the loop from the Ajax script:

```
$(xml).find('ref').each(function () {
  // set thumbs and big image paths
  var thumbUrl = 'img/thumbs/';
  var bigUrl = 'img/';

  $('<a />')
  .append($('<img>').prop('src', thumbUrl + img).attr('alt', alt))
  .prop('href', bigUrl + img)
  .prop('title', title)
  .prop('alt', alt)
  .attr('data-gallery', '')
  .appendTo($('#links'));
});
```

The result looks like this:

```
<div id="links">
  <a href="img/apple.jpg" title="Apple" data-gallery="">
  <img src="img/thumbs/apple.jpg" alt="Apple"></a>

  <a href="img/orange.jpg" title="Orange" data-gallery="">
  <img src="img/thumbs/orange.jpg" alt="Orange"></a>
</div>
```

I'd like to display each image link inside a column class "col-md-3" like this:

```
<div id="links">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="img/apple.jpg" title="Apple" data-gallery="">
    <img src="img/thumbs/apple.jpg" alt="Apple"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="img/orange.jpg" title="Orange" data-gallery="">
    <img src="img/thumbs/orange.jpg" alt="Orange"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrap

```
$('#links a').wrap('<div class="col-md-3">');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xwLmm1d0/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would generate complete HTML code before inserting into DOM. It saves resources, also you can actually see what you insert:

```js
xml = $.parseXML( '<ref img="350x150" alt="Alt 1" title="Title 1"></ref>' );

var newItemHtml = '';
var thumbUrl = 'https://placehold.it/';
var bigUrl = 'https://placehold.it/';
var links = $('#links');

$(xml).find('ref').each(function(i) {
    var thisRef = $(this);
    var src = thumbUrl + thisRef.attr('img');
    var href = bigUrl + thisRef.attr('img');
    var alt = thisRef.attr('alt');
    var title = thisRef.attr('title');
    newItemHtml += '<div class="col-md-3">\n';
    newItemHtml += '    <a href="' + href + '" title="' + title + '" data-gallery="">\n';
    newItemHtml += '        <img src="' + src + '" alt="' + alt + '">\n';
    newItemHtml += '    </a>\n';
    newItemHtml += '</div>\n';
});

links.append(newItemHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="links"></div>
```

Also on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ftou7zxe/).

Comment: Thanks for this. Really helpful.